# Wait for a process to kill or stop and then restart from a service

Tags: c#, windows, process, waithandle

In my C# application I have a requirement that a service will continuously monitor a process. and if the process gets kill or stop by some way or by user it has to be started. And the service will start / restart the process.
I am able to mange to start a exe from a process and if the process gets killed by the user or by any chance the service will restart the process. But I have a problem here.

How I did it is like this

```
string ProcessName = "Notepad++";
String appName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Notepad++.exe";
System.Diagnostics.Process[] proc = System.Diagnostics.
                                    Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessName);

if (proc.Length > 0)
{
}
else
{
     // start the process
     AppLoader.PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo;
     bool result = AppLoader.StartProcess(appName, out procInfo);
}


//Check if the process is running or not.
while (true)
{
     Int32 result2 = WaitForMultipleObjects(.....);
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

the AppLoader code inside I have StartProces and it has a WIn 32 API `CreateProcessAsUser`

```
bool result = CreateProcessAsUser(hUserTokenDup,        
                                        null,                   
                                        applicationName,       
                                        ref sa,                 
                                        ref sa,                 
                                        false,                  
                                        dwCreationFlags,        
                                        IntPtr.Zero,           
                                        null,                   
                                        ref si,                 
                                        out procInfo            
                                        );
```

This is starting the process.

Now when my service starts at the first time the process start but if I kill the process it didn't start, so I come to know that I have to use `WaitForMultipleObject Win32 API` and get it done. I checked in google but there is no code examples for `WaitForMultipleObject`, can anyone please help me to show examples of `WaitForMultipleObject`.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with your code(indeed I don't see any code which starts the process at all) and how `WaitForMultipleObject` will help here? Post the code inside `StartProcess`. Note that `WaitForMultipleObject` is nothing but `WaitHandle.WaitAll` or `WaitHandle.WaitAny` method.

Comment: How do you make sure that code snippet happen more than once?

Comment: Please see the code is updated, last time I forget the put the while part, inside while I need to use the WaitForMultipleObjects

Comment: Why are you using the native WinAPI method and not the managed [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) class to start a process?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I would love to, but Process.IsExit or Process.Kill is costly operation. Because it will keep watching the process so it will take lots of CPU cycle. I can start a process  using Process.Start but again restarting is having issue

Comment: Why not register to `Process.Exited` event? that way you dont have to block and waste any CPU cycles